# Simple array "manager"

Tags: beginner, rust

I'm new to Rust, coming from C++, and so to increase my knowledge of Rust I made a small program to manage an array. You can add, insert, delete, print and more an array or its elements.

I don't really care much about performance at this point, but more on readability, good practices and so on.

So, what could I have done better?

```
use std::io;

fn get_element() -> i64 {
    println!("Enter the element: ");

    let mut element = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut element).expect("Failed to read line!");

    match element.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Invalid number! Try again.");
            get_element()
        }
    }
}

fn get_index(length: usize) -> usize {
    println!("Enter the index: ");

    let mut index = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut index).expect("Failed to read line!");

    match index.trim().parse() {
        Ok(index) if index < length => index,
        Ok(index) => {
            println!("Invalid index! {} is not in range [0, {})! Try again.", index, length);
            get_index(length)
        },
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Invalid number! Try again.");
            get_index(length)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Welcome to the Vector application!");

    let mut vec: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();

    loop {
        println!("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-");
        println!("What do you want to do?");
        println!("1. Clear the vector");
        println!("2. Add element");
        println!("3. Insert element at pos");
        println!("4. Delete an element at index");
        println!("5. Print an element");
        println!("6. Print vector");
        println!("*. Exit");

        let mut input = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read line");
        let input: u8 = match input.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) if num < 7 => num,
            Ok(num) => {
                println!("{} is not in the range [0, 6]!", num);
                continue;
            }
            Err(_) => {
                break;
            }
        };

        let length = vec.len();

        if input == 1 {
            vec.clear();
        }
        else if input == 2 {
            vec.push(get_element());
        }
        else if input == 3 {
            vec.insert(get_index(length), get_element());
        }
        else if input == 4 {
            vec.remove(get_index(length));
        }
        else if input == 5 {
            println!("The element is: {}", match vec.get(get_index(vec.len())) {
                Some(element) => element,
                None => {
                    println!("Invalid index!");
                    continue;
                }
            });
        }
        else if input == 6 {
            for i in &vec {
                println!("{} ", i.to_string());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Become familiar with [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt). For example, `else` goes on the same line as the previous closing brace:

   ```
   -        }
   -        else if input == 2 {
   +        } else if input == 2 {
   ```
2. Rust doesn't do tail call optimization, so unbounded recursive calls are better replaced with iteration.
3. I might extract a function that does the reading from standard input, trimming, and parsing.
4. No need for a type on the `vec`; inference will kick in.
5. You can use `match` with values like numbers. This can be used to replace the large if-else chain at the end of `main`.
6. Move the command out-of-range check/warning from the "parse" match to the match of the command value. This groups the error text closer to the place that will change.
7. I wouldn't embed the match inside the `println!`; it's not obvious enough. Instead, put the print inside the match.
8. Can then remove the `continue` because that's the normal flow
9. Don't convert the number to a string to print it; numbers implement `Display`.
10. You check the index twice; once when getting the value, once when actually indexing. Remove one or the other.

```
use std::io;

fn parsed_line<T>() -> Result<T, T::Err>
    where T: std::str::FromStr
{
    let mut element = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut element).expect("Failed to read line!");
    element.trim().parse()
}

fn get_element() -> i64 {
    loop {
        println!("Enter the element: ");

        match parsed_line() {
            Ok(num) => return num,
            Err(_) => println!("Invalid number! Try again."),
        }
    }
}

fn get_index(length: usize) -> usize {
    loop {
        println!("Enter the index: ");

        match parsed_line() {
            Ok(index) if index < length => return index,
            Ok(index) => {
                println!("Invalid index! {} is not in range [0, {})! Try again.", index, length);
            },
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Invalid number! Try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Welcome to the Vector application!");

    let mut vec = Vec::new();

    loop {
        println!("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-");
        println!("What do you want to do?");
        println!("1. Clear the vector");
        println!("2. Add element");
        println!("3. Insert element at pos");
        println!("4. Delete an element at index");
        println!("5. Print an element");
        println!("6. Print vector");
        println!("*. Exit");

        let input: u8 = match parsed_line() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => break,
        };

        let length = vec.len();

        match input {
            1 => vec.clear(),
            2 => vec.push(get_element()),
            3 => vec.insert(get_index(length), get_element()),
            4 => {
                vec.remove(get_index(length));
            },
            5 => println!("The element is: {}", vec[get_index(length)]),
            6 => {
                for i in &vec {
                    println!("{} ", i);
                }
            }
            other => println!("{} is not in the range [0, 6]!", other),
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! :) I understand every point, except number 5. Do you refer to my huge if chain for the `input`?

Comment: @Rakete1111 ah, yes. I forgot to change that from my silly notes to myself to something that a normal human could understand; I've updated now.

Comment: Rust doesn't do _guaranteed_ tail call elimination. (yet. Still hoping, we've got the `become` keyword reserved for just such a feature)